# EF Core not reading connection string from Web.Config

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I have the following configuration, noting that i'm not using a .net core application, but a simple webform with no `appsettings.json` but a `Web.config` file:

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
   // DBSets ...

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   { 
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContext"].ConnectionString);
   }
}
```

EF core doesn't seem to compile the connection strings from `Web.config` when I execute `update-database` on the project with the data context.

Here's what i keep getting:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Web.Config

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;"   />
</connectionStrings>
```

As you can see i have followed microsoft's documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings). Hard coding the connection string works fine. Any Clue?

Comment: Could you share your entire web.config (redacted if necessary)? Does rebooting fix the issue?

Comment: @mjwills  sure, i uploaded it here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j5XFuMNlKk3RxEB8VC73ZWuK7WSevbAT

Comment: Does the null reference exception point to the OnConfiguring method specificall, or somewhere else? Are other parts of your application able to access the config file? Is this issue limited to running the db update, or does it also occur when the application runs?

Comment: One possible reason is that you are running your update script on the DAL project, not the web project, and thus the config file doesn't exist (in scope of the DAL project). But I don't know your solution structure so I can't judge that right now. When you update the database, what project is set as the startup project (in your solution), and what project is set as the default projects (in Nuget Manager Console)?

Comment: @Flater there is no DAL, and the problem is limited only when using Nuget Package Manager Console to execute EF Core commands like `update-database`. also the startup project is my .net web app